# Avoid compile-time error on asp.net web site with custom ResourceProvider

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have an asp.net web site with our own DbResourceProvider. The plan was to localize pages with regular markup for resources: `Text="<%$ Resources: Someword %>"`.

The provider returns the resourceKey if a resource is missing in the database so missing resources are ok at run-time. However at [compile-time missing resources causes build-errors](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/04/Custom-Localization-ResourceProviders-and-Compiler-Errors).

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

(I'll add more details about my attempts if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

A collegue pointed out at a solution in the last comment in [the blog-post linked](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/04/Custom-Localization-ResourceProviders-and-Compiler-Errors) to in the question. I don't have access to try it, but this class should solve the problem:

```
public class MyResources : System.Web.Compilation.IResourceProvider
{
private static string _entryMethod;

System.Resources.IResourceReader System.Web.Compilation.IResourceProvider.ResourceReader { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

object System.Web.Compilation.IResourceProvider.GetObject(string resourceKey, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (ASPNetCompilerExecutionContext)
        return "ASPNetCompilerDesignTimeExecutionContext";

    return "TODO: return actual resource";      
}

static bool ASPNetCompilerExecutionContext
{
    get
    {
        if (_entryMethod == null) 
            _entryMethod = (new StackTrace()).GetFrame((new StackTrace()).FrameCount - 1).GetMethod().Name;

        if (_entryMethod == "PrecompileApp")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
}
```

I guess an even simpler way would be to pretend all resources are present and return `"missing"` for missing resources.